# Xcode swift thread 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var Web: UIWebView!

    var URLpath = "https://jgrade.caddoschools.org/progress/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    loadaddressURL()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        }

    func loadaddressURL(){

        let requestURL = NSURL(string: URLpath)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        Web.loadRequest(request)

    }
}
```

I am trying to connect a webview but just can't get it to work correctly and I am not sure why, so if you could help please do.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Thread 1 signal SIGBART @MaximillianLaumeister

Answer (score 0):

The web page loaded for me when I did this:

```
let url = NSURL(scheme: "https", host: "jgrade.caddoschools.org", path: "/progress")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

If it's not working for you. Make sure the web view is connected from your storyboard. Make sure the WebView has the appropriate auto layout constraints so you can see it.

Comment: @eli_shade did you add this or replace it for something else?

Comment: I just had a blank ViewController with those three lines in the viewDidLoad under the super.viewDidLoad(). With webView being the IBOutlet for the UIWebView.